pgf plots-Shifting the tick label down while changing the decimal seperator to comma (,)
I am working on a report in German, so the 1000x separator should be a period (.) and the decimal point should be a comma (,). I can format the PGF plot tick labels easily with,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={.}

But, now I want to shift the tick labels of x-axis down a little. Normally, the following works fine.
xticklabel style={yshift=-5pt,},

But these two formattings do not work together.

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/yshift', to . \end{axis}

How to use both both formatting together?
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openany,ngerman,]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight, 
        ylabel={Y-Axis Label}, xlabel={X-Axis Label},
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        axis lines=box,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={.}},
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={.},,
            },
%       xticklabel style={yshift=-5pt,},
        ]
        \addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1,0.8)};
        \addlegendentry{Line 1}
        \addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {(0,0.8) (0.5,0.3) (1,0)};
        \addlegendentry{Line 2}
        \addplot[color=green, mark=*] coordinates {(0,0.4) (0.5,0.7) (1,0.5)};
        \addlegendentry{Line 3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! If you say /pgf/number format/.cd,, you change the path for all following options. So, either you place yshift=-5pt before this, or you need to explicitly state the full path using /tikz/yshift=-5pt.

Hi Jasper, placing the yshift=-5pt above the /pgf/number format/.cd, worked fine. Thank you very much for the clarification.

If you say /pgf/number format/.cd, you change the path for all following options inside the relevant key (xticklabel style here). Therefore, if you later say yshift=-5pt for the same key, this is interpreted as /pgf/number format/yshift=-5pt which is not a valid key path.
There are several solutions here: you can place yshift=-5pt before setting the path with .cd, or you need to explicitly state the full path using /tikz/yshift=-5pt, or you can change the path again ...
So you can say:
xticklabel style={yshift=-5pt},
xticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.},
},

or:
xticklabel style={
    yshift=-5pt,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.},
},

or make the path explicit:
xticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.},
},
xticklabel style={
    /tikz/yshift=-5pt
}

or you can also revert the path using /tikz/.cd:
xticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={.},
    /tikz/.cd
},
xticklabel style={
    yshift=-5pt
}

and finally, you can also not change the path at all and say:
xticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/use comma,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},
},
xticklabel style={
    yshift=-5pt
}

